# APK installation programmatically on Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-6.0-marshmallow

In one of my use case the application in the beginning contacts server and downloads the update of the same application.

For downloading I am using DownloadManager class of Android.
Then using below code it tries to create app installer intent in `onReceive()` i.e. after the APK is downloaded successfully.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //check if the broadcast message is for our Enqueued download
    long referenceId = intent.getLongExtra(DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, -1);
    if (downloadReference == referenceId) {
        try {
            Log.v("", "Downloading of the new app version complete");

            String filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/" + mLatestVersionFileName;

            //start the installation of the latest version
            Uri uri = downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference);

            //downloadManager.getUriForDownloadedFile(downloadReference)
            Uri fileLoc = Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath));

            Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            promptInstall.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(promptInstall);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

The code works fine for Pre-Marshmallow devices and user gets the screen to install APK.

This does not works on Marshmallow device.

I am getting following exception on Marshmallow:

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/my_downloads/287 typ=application/vnd.android.package-archive flg=0x10000000 }

I have tried following things:

1. Using the exact PackageInstaller of Marshmallow `(com.google.android.packageinstaller/com.android.packageinstaller.PackageInstallerActivity)` component name as part of Intent.
2. Passing fileLoc instead of uri.

```
promptInstall.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
```

This results in 'Parse error'.

Ideally intents are resolved by Android OS. I guess its not a big issue and I maybe missing something while creating Intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this out

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {
                    long downloadId = intent.getLongExtra(
                            DownloadManager.EXTRA_DOWNLOAD_ID, 0);
                    Query query = new Query();
                    query.setFilterById(enqueue);
                    Cursor c = dm.query(query);
                    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                        int columnIndex = c
                                .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                        if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL == c
                                .getInt(columnIndex)) {

                            ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                            String uriString = c
                                    .getString(c
                                            .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));

                             //start the installation of the latest version
                            Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriString); 
                            Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            promptInstall.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            promptInstall.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            mContext.startActivity(promptInstall);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Can you try this :**

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String action = intent.getAction();

        if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action)) {

            DownloadManager.Query query = new DownloadManager.Query();
            query.setFilterById(yourDownloadID);
      DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            Cursor downloadResult = dm.query(query);

            if (downloadResult.moveToFirst()) {
                int statusColumnIndex = downloadResult.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                int status = downloadResult.getInt(statusColumnIndex);

                if (status == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                    //download completed successfully
                    int localFileNameId = downloadResult.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_FILENAME);

                    String downloadPathFile = downloadResult.getString(localFileNameId);

       Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(new File(downloadPathFile)), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
}
```